# How to reliably pair a thread to an object instance in a concurrency::parallel_for?

Tags: c++, ppl

I have a vector of M images that has to be processed in parallel by up to N threads, where N is a parameter set by the user.

I also have a vector of N `Detector` instances that take care of the processing, but each instance must run in its own thread (i.e., if two threads call `detect()` on the same instance before the previous call ended, bad things will happen).

`Detector` is a self-contained class (that I can modify if necessary) with one `void Detector::detect(cv::Mat image)` method I call that alters the internal state of the detector for the duration of the (lengthy) detection process (hence the need to prevent parallel calls of `detect()` from different threads).

I originally implemented this with OpenMP as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(N)
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
    detectors[omp_get_thread_num()].detect(images[i]);
}
```

However, since the detection can throw exceptions, I thought of using PPL's `parallel_for` instead, which comes with thread-originated-exception catching in the main thread.

The problem is, I can't find an equivalent of `omp_get_thread_num` that I can use to map a `Detector` to a specific thread:

```
concurrency::CurrentScheduler::Create( concurrency::SchedulerPolicy( 2, 
concurrency::MinConcurrency, 1, concurrency::MaxConcurrency, N ) );
concurrency::parallel_for(0, M, [&](int i)
{
    detectors[?????].detect(images[i]);
});
concurrency::CurrentScheduler::Detach(); // clear scheduler
```

How can I ensure that one thread always uses the same instance from the detectors pool?
Or, if this is the wrong approach, how can I map the execution of `detect()` over the pool of detectors I already have?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if detector is a simple class, why not create one for each image? It might not be optimal but if it's simple, and the process of detecting is much more time consuming, the impact will be minimal. Unless of course there is a reason you can't do that.

Comment: You could use some sort thread safe queue (PPL has a concurrent queue), and then in your lambda function `pop` the first detector out, call `detect`, and then push it pack into the queue when done.  This lets the thread use whatever detector is available.

Comment: @Qubit I definitely misused the word "simple" there. No, the detector is quite massive, it just have a "simple" interface. The main problem there is GPU memory. I have N detectors, each allotted about N/4 GPU memory. The number of images can get too big for me to keep the same number of detectors and images while still having enough GPU memory to run detection.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's a good approach, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @GPhilo Cool, let me know how it goes.  You'll probably want to store a smart pointer to the detector in the queue so you don't copy the detector.

Comment: Yeah I'm already working with smart pointers in the vector actually, so that was the way I'd go anyway

Answer (score 0):

Upon suggestion from @NathanOliver, I ended up using a `concurrent_queue` to solve the issue:

```
using namespace concurrency;
CurrentScheduler::Create( SchedulerPolicy( 2, 
MinConcurrency, 1, MaxConcurrency, N ) );
concurrent_queue<std::shared_ptr<Detector>> detectors_queue;
for(auto& det : obj->instances)
{
    detectors_queue.push(det);
}
parallel_for(0, M, [&](int i)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Detector> thread_det = nullptr;
    while(!detectors_queue.try_pop(thread_det))
    {
        wait(100);
    }
    thread_det->detect(images[i]);
    detectors_queue.push(thread_det);
});
CurrentScheduler::Detach(); // clear scheduler
```